Internal Server Error on Save / Dashboard
A client's site is producing Internal Server Errors randomly in the Craft backend (3.7.53.1). The Dashboard produces an error. Saving certain entries produces an error (especially when enabling entires.
I have done the following:

Increased Memory Limits to 512M
Checked PHP Errors (nothing)
Checked web.log. It's very hard to make sense of this. There are no clear error messages here
Checked System Report (nothing obvious).


If the Internal Server Error was generated by Apache/nginx, then the underlying error should be in the web server's error lots. Did you check those?

Yah, and not much...  Only errors Im seeing are:
mod_fcgid: error reading data, FastCGI server closed connection;
util_script.c(506): End of script output before headers: php73_wrapper.sh

Sounds like you’re running Apache. This is on a production site? It feels like you're hitting some timeout somewhere in the stack. I'd hit up your hosting provider, show them the error, and see what they suggest. Chances are they've seen the error before and know a solution.

Thank you for all the comments and Tommy at Craft for assistance on this. After speaking with the host, we upgrades php from 7.3 to 8.2 and upgraded Craft to the final version of Craft 3. This has resolved the issue!
